# can't build my app apk with buildozer in Google Colab

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I watched a short tutorial with deploying kivy/kivymd apps to apk, i have done everything but mine won't build.
I always get error while debugging the app in google colab.

```
py file:
import kivy
import kivymd
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import plyer
import qrcode
from kivy.uix.image import Image
Window.size = 360,640

KV = """
<MyGrid>:
    Screen:
        name: "fir"
        fname: fname
        content: content
        MDLabel:
            text: "Qr Code Generator"
            font_size: 30
            halign: "center"
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.9}
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: .4
            padding: "10dp"
            MDTextField:
                id: fname
                hint_text: "Enter File Name..."
                halign: "center"
                pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.99, "top": 1}
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: .4
            padding: "10dp"
            MDTextField:
                id: content
                hint_text: "Enter Url..."
                halign: "center"
                pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.7, "top": 1}
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 1.5
            padding: "10dp"
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: "Generate"
                text_color: "white"
                md_bg_color: "#800000"
                size_hint: .1,0.05
                pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.16}
                halign: "center"
                on_press: root.Generate(root)
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: "View Image"
                text_color: "white"
                size_hint: .1,.05
                pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.16}
                halign: "center"
                md_bg_color: "#000080"
                on_press: root.CheckErrorview_image(root)
    Screen:
        name: "image"
        MDLabel:
            text: "Qr Code"
            font_size: 30
            size_hint_y: .2
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.9, "top": 1}
            halign: "center"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: .6
            padding: 20
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5}
            halign: "center"
            Image:
                id: img_
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Make Another"
            text_color: "white"
            md_bg_color: "#000080"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.1}
            on_press: root.current = "fir"
            """

class MyGrid(ScreenManager):
    temp = 0
    def Generate(self, root):
        if self.ids.fname.text == "" or self.ids.content.text == "":
            plyer.notification.notify(
                title= "Qr Code Generator", message= "Error: Type Something in Textfields."
            )
        else:
            self.temp = 1    
            qr = qrcode.QRCode(version= 1, box_size=10, border= 2)
            qr.add_data(self.ids.content.text)
            qr.make()
            img = qr.make_image()
            img = img.resize((300, 300))
            img.save(str(self.ids.fname.text) + ".png")
            plyer.notification.notify(
                title= "Qr Code Generator", message= "Qr Code Generated Successfully"
            )
            
    def CheckErrorview_image(self,root):
        if self.temp == 0:
            plyer.notification.notify(
                title= "Qr Code Generator", message= "Error: First Generate a Qr Code."
            )
        else:
            self.temp = 0
            return self.view_image(root)
    def view_image(self, root):
        self.ids.img_.source = f"{str(self.ids.fname.text)}.png"
        root.current = "image"
        self.ids.fname.text = ""
        self.ids.content.text = ""
class mainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.kvs = Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Indigo"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Blue"
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainApp().run()
```

I change the name to main.py too but it doesnt work.
my spec:

```
# (str) Title of your application
title = app

# (str) Package name
package.name = qrapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd,plyer,qrcode,pillow

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (list) Supported orientations
# Valid options are: landscape, portrait, portrait-reverse or landscape-reverse
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY
```

I only copied the part that is important for building.
if you could check out if I did the requirements part ok.
please I need this fast.

........................

Comment: Hello, did you ever fix this?